# Can you write part of a library in rust (pyo3) but the rest in python?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I want to write part of a python module in rust (with PYo3) but also partly in python, so something like...

src/utils.rs:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyfunction]
fn sum_as_string(a: usize, b: usize) -> PyResult<String> {
    Ok((a + b).to_string())
}

#[pymodule]
fn nvm(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(sum_as_string, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

src/main.py:

```py
from .utils import sum_as_string

...
```

Mostly just curious if this is possible with pyo3 or if I have to write everything in rust, cuz I've seen something like this done with C/Cython ([example](https://github.com/Neoteroi/BlackSheep/tree/main/blacksheep)).

Comment: Well, yeah, that's what pyo3 is for. And your example seems to be taken from their [README](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/main/README.md) directly. What's the problem?

Comment: @wim I don't know how to have a pyo3 project with certain python files and certain rust files where I can import rust files from python and vice versa (within the module). Also the example was just meant to show what I mean to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Maturin is the project you'll want to look through for doing this as pyo3 is simply the bindings to the python runtime. You can see documentation on a mixed python/rust project [here](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin#mixed-rustpython-projects)